# Maximo Anywhere lookup filtering

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working in Maximo Anywhere 7.6.4 - WorkExecution.

I wanted to filter the labor lookup based on the defsite of the connected user .

Let's say the user defsite is ='AAA' then the labors that have to appear are the labors who are in the site AAA

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
<whereClause clause="spi:worksite=${defsite}" id="additionallaborcraftrate_whereClause"/>
```

Comment: I don't know anything about Anywhere, but I'll see if I can help. It looks odd that `spi:` is inside your `clause`. Regular Maximo would see `:worksite` and try to replace it with the value of `worksite` from the parent object. So, I'm inclined to take out `spi:`. and I don't know that `${defsite}` will wrap the `defsite` value (from some Java?) with single quotes, so I would put them in. So, the `clause` I would try is `clause="worksite='${defsite}'"`.

Comment: That clause is assuming that `defsite` is a variable that is in scope at that point in time.