# Maximo Anywhere Lookup function filter

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

hi am new to maximo anywhere and i have a task which is to make the lookup only show the labors that are the same site to the connected user so if the user's defsite = ALN for exmple
the labors with a worksite = ALN are only shown heres the function and thank you

````
    ```filterLaborCraftRateForLookup: function(eventContext){
        var laborCraftRateSet =  CommonHandler._getAdditionalResource(eventContext,"additionallaborcraftrate");
        CommonHandler._clearFilterForResource(eventContext, laborCraftRateSet);
        var orgid = CommonHandler._getWorkorderOrgId(eventContext);
        var filter = [];
        filter.push({'orgid':orgid , 'worksite':defsite});
        laborCraftRateSet.lookupFilter = filter;
    },```
````

Comment: it is unclear what exactly you are asking or what is going wrong with the code provided. What are you expecting to happen? What is happening instead?

Comment: This question looks like [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74861508/maximo-anywhere-lookup-filtering).